# The max of the modulus of difference of a continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I=[a,b]$ be a closed real interval

Let $f: I \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function such that $|f(x)|$ is strictly decreasing

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\max_{x,y \in I}
|f(x)-f(y)|
=
|f(a)-f(b)|
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, consider the spiral

$$f(t):=(1-t)e^{4\pi it}$$

with $t\in[0,1/2]$. The modulus is of course decreasing and we have
$$
|f(1/2)-f(0)|=1/2.
$$ 
However,
$$
|f(1/4)-f(0)|=7/4.$$

Comment: $|f(1/4)-f(0)|=1/4$ not $7/4$

Comment: Yeah, my bad, it should work now!

Comment: ok, thanks @user128470 it's work

Comment: increasing function was the same. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. Set 
$$
f: [0,2] \to \mathbf{C}: x \mapsto \begin{cases}(1-x)+i \,\,& \text{ if }x \in [0,1]\\
\frac{x-1}{2}+i\,\frac{3-x}{2} & \text{ if }x \in [1,2].
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: it's not a monotone function $|f|$

Comment: It is the function defined by the path $(1,1) \mapsto (0,1) \mapsto (1/2,1/2)$, now it should be better